# Why was my flag on a troll question declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging

[This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/133169/moving-large-amounts-of-money) (which is currently closed as off-topic, and deleted) comes from a known troll account. They're currently suspended on two other sites for trolling, and their MSO account was nuked entirely for repeated trolling.

Believing that this is also a troll question, I flagged this post as Rude/Abusive. However, a moderator declined it, citing lack of evidence.

Why was that? Was I correct in flagging this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might have been me.
If so, I thought I was responding to a flag on your comment. In other words, I thought that the OP flagged your comment as rude to him.

In hindsight, I see what happened, it was actually you flagging the question. And I apologize for that. Keep in mind, the question was already closed when you flagged.

Comment: That interface is super confusing. I can never figure out what is being flagged. I always just go to the original post and clean it up there.

Answer (score 5):

This is a case where you should use a custom flag rather than a standard one. Rude/abusive doesn't convey the extra information you're mentioning here to the moderator handling the flag.

I've deleted the post now.